# Why can't I create a new analyzer/code fix provider project after installing the Roslyn SDK?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, roslyn, visual-studio-2017

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 RC. I just installed the .NET Compiler Platform SDK from [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.NETCompilerPlatformSDK) into my installation. I also installed the VS Extensibility Tools from [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.ExtensibilityTools). However, I'm not seeing any Analyzer/Code Fix Provider templates when I trigger the New Project dialog:

[image]

I have tried uninstalling/reinstalling the Roslyn SDK extension, but the templates still do not show up. I have also tried re-launching the VS 2017 installer, clicking *Modify*, going to the 2nd tab *Installed products*, and checking for anything relating to Roslyn, but there's nothing there.

What can I do to make the templates show up? Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to be targeting .NET Framework 4.6 or higher in the dropdown at the top of that dialog.